# Show different images for each list item with React onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave

Tags: reactjs, image, hover, listitem

I'm new with React and before writing here I looked everywhere for my problem:
I have a list with four items, and I want to show on hover different image for each item.

```
const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
            href="/"
          >
            Item1
          </a>
          {isShown && (
            <div style={{ width: `width: 300px` }}>
              <img
                className="image"
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1145720/pexels-photo-1145720.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260"
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </li>
         ...
```

I have used this procedure for each **`<li>`** but no matter which item I hover, all images are shown.

Can someone help me? Thank you

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-resonance-lnl8i?file=/src/App.js) the example

**Update**

I tried to use arrays as suggested by John but I am doing something wrong because the images are shown all together:

```
const projects = [
  { id: 1, title: "Item1" },
  { id: 2, title: "Item2" },
  { id: 3, title: "Item3" },
  { id: 4, title: "Item4" }
];

const images = [
  {image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600", id: 1},
  {image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600", id: 2},
  {image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600", id: 3},
  {image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600", id: 4},
];
function Portfolio(props) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="wrap">
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="wrap">
            {props.projects.map((project, image) => (
              <li key={project.id}>
                <a
                  onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
                  href="/"
                >
                  {project.title}
                </a>
                {isShown && (
                  <img key={image.id} src={image} style={{position: `absoulte` }}/>
                )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using the same flag `isShown` to show all of the images. What you should do is change it from a `boolean` to a `int` and assign an index to it.

```
onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(1)}
onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(0)}

..

onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(2)}
onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(0)}

... etc
```

So for each image you'd have something like this

```
isShown === 1 && (
  ...code
)

isShown === 2 && (
  ...code
)
```

This way each image will depend on a specific value, making each of them independent.

A small suggestion. Since the code you're printing is redundant, I suggest you create an `array` of your items and map them on the render instead of printing each item manually. Let me know if you have more questions about this.

---

**Update:**

I think there was a misunderstanding in what my suggestion was. I'm adjusting your code now, maybe now it will much clearer.

```
function Portfolio(props) {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  const projects = [
    { id: 1, title: "Item1", image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600" },
    { id: 2, title: "Item2", image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600" },
    { id: 3, title: "Item3", image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600" },
    { id: 4, title: "Item4", image: "https://placekitten.com/800/600" }
  ];

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="wrap">
        <div className="container">
          <ul className="wrap">
            {projects.map((project, image) => (
              <li key={project.id}>
                <a
                  onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(project.id)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(0)}
                  href="/"
                >
                  {project.title}
                </a>
                {isShown === project.id && (
                  <img src={project.image} style={{position: `absoulte` }}/>
                )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @opanopono I updated my answer, let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have a TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. 
[here's the full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-moon-s2ngz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @opanopono you need to either pass the `projects` to the `Portfolio` component as a prop when you render it or declare it inside the component.

Comment: @opanopono I just edited the code so you can have a better look.